# How to add namespace at the time of xml serialization

Tags: c#

```
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(OpenShipments));
            var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("x-schema:", @"x-schema:C:\UPSLabel\OpenShipments.xdr");
            serializer.Serialize(writer, OS, ns);
            xmlString = sb.ToString();
```

getting error object reference not found because i add namespace programatically.
basically in my xml namespace will look like below one

```
<OpenShipments xmlns="x-schema:C:\UPSLabel\OpenShipments.xdr">
```

here i add the line `ns.Add("x-schema:", @"x-schema:C:\UPSLabel\OpenShipments.xdr");`

and for the above line i am getting error....what is my mistake. just can not figure out. please help me to construct the namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var myns = @"x-schema:C:\UPSLabel\OpenShipments.xdr";
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(OpenShipments), myns);
    var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add(string.Empty, myns);
    serializer.Serialize(writer, OS, ns);
    xmlString = sb.ToString();
}
```

will generate:

```
<OpenShipments xmlns="x-schema:C:\UPSLabel\OpenShipments.xdr">
    ...
</OpenShipments>
```

Comment: can u please tell me how to add more namespace. just like ns.Add(string.Empty, myns1);
ns.Add(string.Empty, myns2);
this works?

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
ns.Add("x-schema:", @"x-schema:C:\UPSLabel\OpenShipments.xdr");
```

is adding an *alias*, i.e. allowing the serializer to use `x-schema:` inside the xml. However this doesn't make your **object** use this namespace; for that, you need (on your type):

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace=@"x-schema:C:\UPSLabel\OpenShipments.xdr")]
public class OpenShipments {...}
```

(or something equivalent, perhaps using `XmlAttributeOverrides`)

Note that *with the alias added*, you will get:

```
<x-schema:OpenShipments xmlns:x-schema="x-schema:C:\UPSLabel\OpenShipments.xdr" />
```

To get it without an alias, you want:

```
ns.Add("", @"x-schema:C:\UPSLabel\OpenShipments.xdr");
```

which gives output:

```
<OpenShipments xmlns="x-schema:C:\UPSLabel\OpenShipments.xdr" />
```